# Display Text From a Document's File - iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, text, documents

Does anyone know how to display a text file, if its in the "Documents" folder of the iPhone application? The extension might not always be ".txt", but I would like to give it a try.

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filename];

and throw it in a text field